# Getting [Errno 32] Broken pipe when using django-storages and s3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I am having trouble using django-storages with s3. Everything works using boto (creating and reading back files) so it's not anything to do with credentials.

I have the following keys in settings.py:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '...'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '...'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'sff-dev'
```

I have the following model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

I'm not sure what I should be using for upload_to, if anything. I've also tried '/'.

I have tried various things such as setting AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False and AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

I've been researching this as well. found my solution in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388716/django-collecstatic-boto-broken-pipe-on-large-file-upload) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552242/using-djangos-collectstatic-with-boto-s3-throws-error-32-broken-pipe-after-a)

tl;dr: is that I switched from `django-storages` to `django-storages-redux` and added the below to my `settings.py`:

```
AWS_S3_HOST = "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
```